# AJAX для нескольких объектов на чистом javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть элементы, по которым необходимо асинхронно получать информацию и выводить в отдельный блок при нажатии на кнопку, но я понять не могу, как сделать это.

> **Без каких-либо библиотек**.

Ниже мои потуги:

```
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
</script>
<ul>
    <script>
        xhr.open('GET','function_snmp.php?id=1')
        function sendAJAX() {
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
    <li>город Екатеринбург, улица Сельская, дом 6</li>
    <button onclick="sendAJAX()" class="button">Подробнее</button>
    <div id="ajax"></div>
</ul>
<ul>
    <script>
        xhr.open('GET','function_snmp.php?id=2')
        function sendAJAX() {
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
    <li>город Москва, улица Московская, дом 5</li>
    <button onclick="sendAJAX()" class="button">Подробнее</button>
    <div id="ajax"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: `jQuery` есть возможность использовать?

Comment: @Klimenkomud, нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас изначально ошибка в верстке нельзя двум блокам задавать одинаковый `id`
можно сделать так:

```
<script>
    function sendAJAX(idDOM, id){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'function_snmp.php?id='+id, true)
        var DOM = document.getElementById(idDOM);
        DOM.innerHTML = xhr.responseText
    }
</script>
<ul>
    <li>город Екатеринбург, улица Сельская, дом 6</li>
    <button onclick="sendAJAX('ajax1', 1)" class="button">Подробнее</button>
    <div id="ajax1"></div>
    </ul>
<ul>
    <li>город Москва, улица Московская, дом 5</li>
    <button onclick="sendAJAX('ajax2', 2)" class="button">Подробнее</button>
    <div id="ajax2"></div>
</ul>
```

на странице "function_snmp.php" сформируйте нужный html

Comment: Пришлось немного модифицировать скрипт, но в общем, он работает как положено.
<!-- language: lang-js -->
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', 'function_snmp.php?id=36');

  function sendAJAX() {
    xhr.send( );
  }